# mongodump using --query argument gives "positional arguments not allowed" error

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, database, nosql

I'm using mongodb 2.6 and trying to create a dump using the query option gives "positional arguments not allowed".

I am trying to get all the products who parameter's timestamp is between specified range and whose id is of any of the specified format.

```
 mongodump --host 10.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx --db test --collection products --username abc --password uvw --query '{"parameterList":{$elemMatch:{ "paramName":"TimeStamp","paramValue":{$gte:"20160620000000",$lt:"20160724000000"}}},"parameterList.paramValue": {$in:[/SPC126/,/CSC234/]}}' --authenticationDatabase test --out "c:\New folder\dump"
```

document structure

```
 { 
   "_id": ObjectId("590074c362f41f15144996fa"),
   "product": "device1",
   "parameterList":[{"paramName":"TimeStamp",
                     "paramValue":"20160731000700"},
                    {"paramName":"Id",
                     "paramValue": "SPC126332"}]
  }
```

Comment: So your properties are actually named `"arrayfield"` or are they actually called something else and you are not writing the actual statement you are trying to execute here? It also makes no sense to both use `$elemMatch` and "dot notation" forms in the same query. And your "actual" regular expressions are likely a problem, aside from the incorrect query structure that would not return the correct expected results. In breif, **This is an abstract** and not your **real** query expression. The problem is with the actual expression you are really using. That you did not bother to post here.

Comment: @NeilLunn can you elaborate why it doesn't make sense to use $elemMatch and dot notation in same query. And also I executed the same thing without any issues in mongodb 3.2  using "queryfile" option passing the query as a file and i want to do same on mongo 2.6

Comment: Your question did not make any sense without showing the actual query issued is more the point. The problem is that `$elemMatch` is looking for multiple conditions on the array, being in this case conditions on two different fields. You are adding a "third" condition on exactly the same array path and "outside" of the `$elemMatch`. This does not work in tandem with the other condition, as is likely the intent.

Comment: You are actually missing a "space" here `products--username` which would explain the actual error.

Comment: I cannot post the original query because of business reasons. But i have edited the question with sample document structure.

Comment: I already told you what the error was. "Positional Arguments" has nothing to do with the query itself. It's the "options" specified on the command line. What you originally posted had the error I commented on above, and so will the actual statement you are running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike UNIX `bash`, Windows `cmd.exe` doesn't recognize single quotes as a delimiter.

Running your example command as-is in `cmd.exe` gives the error:

```
Error parsing command line: too many positional options
```

Try changing your quotes around, replacing the single quotes with double quotes and vice versa. For example, using the example command you posted:

```
mongodump --host 10.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx --db test --collection products --username abc --password uvw --query "{'parameterList':{$elemMatch:{ 'paramName':'TimeStamp','paramValue':{$gte:'20160620000000',$lt:'20160724000000'}}},'parameterList.paramValue': {$in:[/SPC126/,/CSC234/]}}" --authenticationDatabase test --out "c:\New folder\dump"
```

Note the `--query "..."` instead of `--query '...'` in the example above.

It should be able to complete the dump successfully.

Comment: Thanks Kevin Adistambha, got this working after enclosing the query in  double quotes and fields and its values in single quotes